# How to create a .mat file to store multiple images and its histograms.

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm new to matlab and would greatly appreciate if anyone could guide me about .MAT file. I'm doing a image retrieval system which requires a database of 1000 images. Currently, i have a .mat file which contains the training data for 100 images but i would like to increase it to 1000 images. How do i edit the .mat file or how do i go about creating a .MAT file which it can store 1000 images and its histograms. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend having a 1000 images plus histograms in one mat file. Matlab is horrible at handling large mat files (+500Mb or so). It crashes often when saving, at least that is my experience. Instead, save one image and histogram in one mat file, place them in one folder, and give the files some meaningful names so you can programmatically find them again. `ls` (Linux) and `dir` (windows) work fine from Matlab and return a listing of a directory for you to use or parse in some way.

Also, you will get a good speed up for cases where you don't have to load all images.

Regards